# Why is Whistler suddenly so concerned about killing vampire-aligned humans?

Tags: blade

I realize that Blade 3: Trinity is generally considered the worst of the Blade movies, but one part in particular bugs me. Throughout the first two movies, we witness Blade killing dozens of familiars - humans who work for the vampires as thugs, guards, etc. Many of them were killed in fairly public venues, albeit ones owned or frequented by vampires.

The plot of Blade 3 largely hinges on the vampires framing Blade for killing one such human, and when Blade returns to his hideout, even Whistler jumps on his case about it:

> **WHISTLER:** What the hell happened tonight?
>
> **BLADE:** How should I know? He was human.
>
> **WHISTLER:** You're getting reckless, Blade. Killing vampires is clean.
>   They ash - don't leave any evidence behind. Killing humans is messy.
>   You better hope nobody ID'd you.

Given the string of human bodies they've left all over the world, this seems very out of character for Whistler. They already live underground, move constantly, and avoid the authorities. Heck, Blade has even run afoul of actual neutral police officers on occasion. I've read online that the movie has a lot of deleted & alternate scenes, so I'm hoping one of them will explain...

**Why does Whistler suddenly care about killing vampire-aligned humans or the evidence?**

Comment: Probably another plot hole : http://alarmedshow.com/wp2/everything-wrong-with-blade-trinity/

Comment: I think he was more worried about Blade leaving evidence for the police to ID him, than just killing a familiar.